# I'm trying to set up a workflow to build PS1 low-poly 2D/3D environments and I have a few questions

Tags: modeling, workflow, 2d, pixel-art

I'm trying to work towards making [3D/2D environments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmkBM.jpg) and assets like those you'd see in PS1 games, specifically games such as Xenogears, Wild Arms 2, and a couple of others. If you're familiar with that era, specifically JRPGs (Japanese Role-Playing Games) you know what I'm talking about. The actual workflow of building the pixel textured 3D assets I'm getting down, but I still have a few questions.

[image: asset with reference pixel guy]

The pixel guy you see is made in [Asesprite](https://www.aseprite.org/); I'm not building the flat 2D assets such as him in Blender, I'm using him as a reference image to compare against the actual 3D objects I'm building in Blender.

Often I need to import a 2D, pixel based reference image to ensure that the 3D assets and environment I'm building match up with one another. When I'm importing a reference image, especially a flat/2D image, how can I make sure that the image is and remains the absolute, objective size that it is? I ask this because sometimes when I import a reference image that otherwise is the same size in Asesprite, in Blender they're wildly different dimensions.

As you can see from the link the reference image I uploaded is blurry; how do I fix that?

How can I check the sizes in pixels of something in Blender? For example, if I'm using 32x32 sized pixel assets it's important for me to check and double check those dimensions in Blender to ensure that everything is in order from time to time.

Any additional tips for what I'm doing? Anything I'm missing in my workflow?

Answer (score 2):

[image: screenshot with the settings]

### Blurry Reference Image

Your reference image is blurry because it's only 32 x 32 pixels small and Blender needs to scale it up to the actual size on the screen. The default algorithm to scale an image is `Linear` which interpolates the pixels. It's a setting of the **Image Texture node**. Switch the *Texture Interpolation* setting from `Linear` to `Closest` and the image will keep the pixelated appearance.

### Units and Sizes

Blender's default *Unit System* is `Metric`. It can be changed in the *Scene properties* but there are only 2 other options: `None` and `Imperial` (inches). No pixels. So it's up to you to create a mapping. For example, you can say that 1 pixel of the reference image is 10 cm in Blender. That way your image would be 32 x 32 cm. 
Of course, when you export the 3D object it will be 32 cm tall. This might be too big or too small in the game engine. It's probably best to import a sample asset into Blender and check the size. Then you will have the correct mapping between pixel and meter.
You can check the Dimensions in the "N-panel", the viewport's side panel. Press <kbd>N</kbd> to open it. There you also can lock the scale values so that you cannot accidentally change the image's size.

### Helper Add-On

Blender comes with an add-on called *"Import-Export: Import Images As Planes"*. You can activate it in the preferences. It might be handy if you need to work with a lot of reference images.